# dynamic insert php mysql and performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, insert

I have a folder/array of images, it may be 1, maximum of 12. What I need to do is dynamically add them so the images are added to an images table.

At the moment I have

```
 $directory = "portfolio_images/$id/Thumbs/";
 $images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

  for ( $i= 0; $i <= count($images); $i += 1) {

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO project_images  (image_name, project_id)VALUES ('$images[0]', '$id')") or die(mysql_error());

 }
```

this is fine but it does not feel right, how is this for performance? Is there a better way?

The maximum number of images is only ever going to be 12.

Answer (score 3):

With this solution, you'll send up to 12 insert queries to the database -- which means up to 12 calls between PHP and MySQL.

A possibly faster way would be to send only one SQL query, that would insert several lines at once.

That SQL query would look like this :

```
INSERT INTO project_images  (image_name, project_id)
VALUES ('image name 1', 'id_1'), 
('image name 2', 'id_2'), 
('image name 3', 'id_3'), 
('image name 4', 'id_4')
```

See [12.2.5. INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) in MySQL's manual -- there's an example of such a query.

This means you could change your code, to build that query, first ; and only then call MySQL once.

Not tested, but I suppose your could would look a bit like this :

```
$values = array();
$directory = "portfolio_images/$id/Thumbs/";
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");
for ( $i= 0; $i <= count($images); $i += 1) {
    $values[] = "('$images[0]', '$id')";
}

$values_str = implode(', ', $value);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO project_images  (image_name, project_id) VALUES $values_str") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have an error in your code. Not $images[0] but `$images[$i]`
2. Your code fail to follow proper SQL syntax.
   `$images[$i]=mysql_real_escape_string($images[$i])`
   must be added
3. Yes, It can be done another way as Pascal mentioned
4. No, there is no performance problem.
5. Using `or die()` is terrible practice, use `or trigger_error()` to handle error message and and a template for user notification